# GAE dispatch.yaml path rules not working

Tags: google-app-engine, routes

I've got a dispatch.yaml like

```
application: myapp

dispatch:
  - url: "www.myapp.com/*"
    module: frontend

  - url: "www.myapp.com/api/*"
    module: api

  - url: "foo.myapp.com/*"
    module: foo
```

The `foo` route works just fine, but requests to `www.myapp.com/api/whatever` get routed to the `frontend` app. I can't get a request to hit the `api` module, as evidenced by the logs.

Why doesn't my dispatch rule work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order matters in dispatch.yaml. GAE uses the first rule that gets matched. Requests to `www.myapp.com/api/whatever` match the `www.myapp.com/*` wildcard, so the `frontend` module is used for those.

Switch the order of those rules to read:

```
dispatch:
  - url: "www.myapp.com/api/*"
    module: api

  - url: "www.myapp.com/*"
    module: frontend
```

Comment: Yep, very true. People (in this situation, and other GAE YAML file ones) seem to think the matched regexp/wildcard somehow "should" be the "tighter" one, but that would be extremely complex in the general case for both humans and programs -- simply going in order is MUCH simpler... yet users keep making this mistake. Maybe an error diagnostics in cases in which it can be assured that anything matched by a later regexp/wildcard would already have been matched by a previous one would help...?

Comment: @AlexMartelli Or maybe people wouldn't make this mistake as much if the official docs actually *said* that the rules are applied in order, with examples like the one in this question?